# Solana Application Account Initalization

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, solana-cli, anchor-client

how would you go about creating a permanent account on Solana blockchain that represents a pool that holds all the funds.

I created an application in which people can fund the pool and get back interest and then others can borrow that money and pay interest - essentially a lending protocol. **I have problems on how to initialize** the application so there will always be **the same one pool**. (Currently it is done so that user clicks on a button and the "pool" account is created).

Any ideas are welcome. I am only asking this as I have a gap in knowledge about Solana for now.

It is a JS (React + TS) and RUST (Solana + Anchor) project.

```
    const createPool= async () => {
    try {
      // program derived account, bumps and seeds used for calculating the address of our pool account
      const [pool] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [ 
          utils.bytes.utf8.encode("POOL"),
          provider.wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        ],
        program.programId
      );
      console.log(program.programId);
      await program.rpc.createPool({
        accounts: {
          pool,
          user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
          systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        },
      });
      setPool(pool);
      console.log('Created a new pool w/ address:', pool.toString());
    } catch(error) {
      console.error('Error creating pool account:', error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just a PDA with a constant for the seed, like "pool"?

Comment: I have added a code snippet on my PDA function. This is how I have it, I am calling the function on click. I should just call it once on init right. 
How do I check if the pool has already been created? By checking if there is already PDA with POOL seed right. Through this "findProgramAddress( utils.bytes.utf8.encode("POOL"), ..."

Comment: One more question: I cannot just use a PDA with constant seed like "pool" because each user creates then their own pool because of this line: "user: provider.wallet.publicKey,". How can I change this line so the pool is created by only one "superuser"?

Comment: First question -- almost, be careful and notice that what you need to do is pass in an array of byte-arrays! So in your example, the utf-8 encoded bytes you made should be wrapped in yet another array.

Second question -- If it's not "The Pool for the entire program" and instead it's "This user's pool, that user's pool, etc", then simply include the user's 32-byte address as a seed alongside the word "pool" as an additional seed.